# If Qt signals aren't handled because the receiving object's thread has ended, will the arguments be deleted?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, memory-management, memory-leaks

Consider that object A is bound to thread T1 and a signal sig1 with an argument of QList < QVariantMap > is fired from thread T2.

The signal is queued on A's event loop, but before handling, A's thread (T1) is quit.  The QList< QVariantMap > argument of sig1 is obviously allocated on the stack, I'm guessing that it should clean up itself.

But when?  Perhaps when the QThread object itself is destroyed?  Does anyone have specific knowledge in this area?  In my system, this thread will not simply run once and end at shutdown.  It may potentially be started, run for hours, and then quit and be started again later on.

Comment: quit is not equal to destroy, however, which you imply in your post.

Comment: You're right, I should have made the distinction in the post. Though I believe any thread object cannot be restarted after having ended. I haven't seen this mentioned in QThread docs, but I've seen this rule enforced in other threading models (like Java's) which typically leaves the thread object to be deleted after ending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument will not be deleted if the thread has been terminated in a correct way like

```
QThread t;
t.exit();
t.wait();
```

Now you assert that

> The QList< QVariantMap > argument of sig1 is obviously allocated on
>   the stack

It is not that obvious. Because the receiving thread need to use the data in a deferred execution, `emit(myVariantList)` will eventually lead to a copy of `myVariantList`. You don't know where ***the copy*** is going to be allocated.

Now to allow posting events with eventual data , ie the classic

```
Mywidget m;
m.show(); <-- this post at least one event

app.exec();
```

Those posted events need to be saved just in case of an eventual execution of the event loop. I believe that if the object holding the event loop is not destroyed or the user doesn't explicitly ask for events to be removed, they stay for the lifetime of the `QObject`.

Comment: This answer is still a little ambiguous, but it's definitely some good information in the direction that I was looking for.  These kinds of scenarios can be fairly tough to put your finger on during testing, especially when you're building a backend with Qt.  I think it comes down to whether or not the QThread object maintains the queued signal data or if the QObject bound to the QThread maintains it.  In my scenario, both objects will be destroyed when the backend goes idle long enough, meaning that both are destroyed and clean up.

Comment: Indeed it is something which is not explicitly defined. The point is not worry about the exact memory area of allocation but the fact that the data is available as long as the thread object is not deleted.